# UIButton with Linebreak and Autolayout

Tags: ios, uibutton, autolayout, line-breaks

I have a `UIButton` which I set it's text within the app, however the text is too long so I'd like to have the `UIButton` text do a linebreak and continue on the next row.

And it has to work with `AutoLayout`.

I've managed to to so with a `UILabel` with this code:

```
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 300.0;
```

However when I apply it to a button like this:

```
button.titleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 200.0;
button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

it doesn't seem to work.

That code is placed in the `viewDidLoad` like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 300.0;

button.titleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 200.0;
button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0; }
```

And then I set the button text with an IBAction like so

```
-(IBAction)labelMake:(id)sender {

label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Test to see if label linebreaks"];

button.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Test to see if button text linebreaks"];}
```

Comment: Please show your actual code for the button. Where does it run, how is the button created / configured, how do you set the button label text, and so on.

Comment: I've edited my question with the actual code. Please note that I created a new project just to test this features for an app I'm working on.

Comment: "Please note that I created a new project just to test this features" Excellent! I wish everyone would do that. That's the best way to figure these things out.

Comment: I'm still learning to code in Objective - C however I figured it would be easier to do it in a new project to avoid clutter with the current app, and in the worst case mess upp some of the original code in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just setup the `UIButton` with:

```
button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

And set the text with:

```
[button setTitle:@"This is a long text \nspanning multiple lines\nAnd there would be A LOT MORE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```